# Hiding view below toolbar in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm working on creating a layout that works as follows:

### Toolbar at the top

### Toolbar below top toolbar

### RecyclerView

And when I scroll, I want to hide the toolbar in between top toolbar and recyclerView. My Layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="SomeActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/info_bar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

With these changes, both the toolbars become hidden when scrolling. 
I just need to hide the second toolbar.

EDIT : If I can't get this to work, I'll be attaching a scroll listener to my recyclerView and resolving this that way. But I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution with scroll behaviors

Comment: remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from the first Toolbar

Comment: That was my first implementation. If I do that, both toolbars stay there.

Comment: Are you able to make just the top Toolbar collapse by removing that property from the second Toolbar?

Comment: Yup. That works just fine.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe try separating it out into two AppBarLayouts?  Just a shot in the dark....

Comment: ah... independent app bar layouts... didn't think of that... I'll get back with my findings, thanks.

Comment: That didn't work... Bottom app bar overlapped with top one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moved the top toolbar out of the coordinatorlayout and thus resolved this issue.
(Thanks to a colleague)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, then you might want to collapse hole collapseableToolbar when it is scrolled up, instead it is showing some (20dp) space between ToolBar and listItem. for me it took half of the day, and problem is just a boolean value in coordinatorLayout. Just change "fitsSystemWindows" value from true to false.

with this you can hide image of the collapseToolBar upon scrolling.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
  tools:context="com.thedeveloperworldisyours.imagecollapsingtoolbarlayout.ScrollingActivity">
```